# Code formatting is not working in chat

Tags: bug, code-formatting, chat

In [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/37763926#37763926) message, code formatting using backticks is not working, contrary to what is stated in [the official FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting).

Comment: Formatting in general doesn't work if the message contains a line break, it's not only code format.

Comment: Will it be fixed or is it intentional and we just need to avoid using a line break in the chat messages?
I think such information should be included in the FAQ.

Comment: It's been like that forever and is considered as by-design, see [Markdown in chat fails for multi-line messages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70141/164356)

Comment: The FAQ is a little terse, but any linebreaks disable formatting. This is by design; you can indent the whole post and get preformatted text instead (CTRL-K will do this for you).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, messages with line-breaks in them break all markdown formatting, including code, links, `[tag:foo]`...

The only notable exception is indenting the entire message by 4 spaces, which yields code-block formatting for the whole thing.